# partially(conditionally) dashed line

Tags: reactjs, recharts

In my React project, I am using [Rechrts](https://recharts.org/en-US), and I need a Line in my graph but it has to be dashed (strokeDasharray) after some point. So solid for the beginning and then dashed after some conditions.

I searched a lot but couldn't find a solution, is it even possible?

Comment: Could you find the ranges of the lines you draw and split it into sub plots? draw the first section of the line as solid, then plot the second segment of the line as dashed.

Comment: @Danielme that's what I thought, but the problem is we don't know how many dashed sectioned we will have

Comment: Do you have access to the data or can you only set it? Looking at https://recharts.org/en-US/guide/customize they created the web side in python. I am thinking if you can calculate the criteria in code and loop through each data set you can update the sections you want and only update the linetype to monotone and strokeDasharray. I am not familiar with this API so I do not know if breaking up the lines will cause bugs